# Laravel Return Response From Ajax

Tags: laravel

I am trying to learn Laravel9. For this I have Created a Controller, a model and blade view file. Below is my vatprofile.blade.php file code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/vatprofile",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

And this is my Rout,
Route::get('/vatprofile',
[VatProfileController::class,'index']);

And Below is my Controller Function

```
  public function index(){
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Record is successfully added']);
  }
```

It is not Giving Error, Not printing out any response. Only the Blank Page is Showing up. Can you Correct me Pls

Comment: Is the Debug mode is enabled?  just to make sure if there is an error

Comment: Did you clear the route cache with `php artisan route:cache` ? Did you check the console and network tab in the browsers debug tools for errors?

Comment: if you type in on your browsers address: `domain.com/vatprofile` does it display anything?

Comment: yes if I put any html text it is showing but not the ajax response

Comment: Gert B, yes no error is showing up

Comment: Please hit the url from another tab fo your browser. It should return the response. As browser responses all GET http verbs. It will help you to debug very well.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{ url('vatprofile') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? What have you changed? Please add a little explanation

Comment: `url: "/vatprofile",` this works fine. No issues with that.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam it works fine, but still I would change the hardcoded url to `url()` or even better `route()`. But again, you are right, this is not the problem.